# std::list of move-only type: Cannot emplace into std::vector in VC++

Tags: c++, list, visual-c++, move-semantics

In VC++ 2019, I cannot `emplace_back` an (rvalue) `list` of a move-only type.

```
#include <vector>
#include <list>

struct A
{
    A(A&&) {}
};

using ListOfA = std::list<A>;

int main()
{
    std::vector<ListOfA> v;

    // Build error in VC++ 2019
    // No error in Clang and GCC C++11 - C++2a
    v.emplace_back(std::move(ListOfA()));
}
```

Attempting to build in VC++ 2019 gives the following compile error:

`'A::A(const A &)': attempting to reference a deleted function`

Clearly, VC++ is attempting to instantiate the (lvalue) copy constructor for `A`, which (correctly) does not exist because I have explicitly defined one of the constructors for `A`.

I would think that it should be valid to instantiate a `list` in-place in a `vector` by moving from another `list` - that is, the `list` class does have a [move constructor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/list/) which I'd think should simply cause the new `list` to take ownership over the elements in the (moved-from) `list`, without requiring any copies.

In fact, using Wandbox, the [same code builds and runs without error](https://wandbox.org/permlink/P0aVRIthio5ZnyV9) using GCC and Clang.

Can somebody explain why this code does not compile in VC++ 2019?  Do I have a misunderstanding - is there in fact a valid reason why the (lvalue) copy constructor is being instantiated by the VC++ compiler in the code above?

---

**Note**

The same error occurs in VC++ when the `std::move(...)` is not present; i.e. the same error occurs with this line:

`v.emplace_back(ListOfA());`

Comment: Clang prints an interesting message: `warning: moving a temporary object prevents copy elision [-Wpessimizing-move]`

Comment: You don't need to `std::move` a temporary. Try getting rid of `std::move` and see what happens with VC (gcc is perfectly happy).

Comment: @SamVarshavchik My original code does not have the `std::move` operator, and the same error occurs.  I added it for clarity here only.

Comment: What Sam meant is, what happens if you change your code to `v.emplace_back(ListOfA());`

Comment: @NikosC I added a note to my question clarifying that the same error occurs in VC++ without the `std::move`.

Comment: In that case, try to poke around and see if VC perhaps doesn't have a move constructor for `std::list`. Perhaps `std::list` is getting copy-constructed here.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Good idea - I'll try that and post a comment in a bit.

Comment: You may be able to deduce this by looking at all the error message dump, and see which `std::list` constructor is getting invoked. In the alternative, add a copy-constructor to your class, set a breakpoint in the copy constructor, and look at the call stack.

Comment: Seems like a bug; maybe the MSVC `list` implementation doesn't correctly propagate `noexcept`

Comment: In fact, `std::is_nothrow_move_constructible_v<ListOfA>` gives `1` in gcc 9 and `0` in MSVC 19

Comment: When I implement the copy constructor, and place breakpoints both there and in the move constructor, only the move constructor is reached.  The copy constructor is not reached.  Despite `std::is_nothrow_move_constructible_v<ListOfA>` returning false, somehow VC++ **is** calling the `list` move constructor nonetheless

Comment: Ok, now what happens if you explicitly delete the copy constructor?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Replacing the (newly-implemented) copy constructor with an explicit `A(A const&) = delete;` results in the same compiler error as noted in the question.

Comment: Doesn't `list<T>` require T be copy constructable?

Comment: @doug At first I thought that might be the explanation, but I wonder why `list` has `emplace_back` (though that could be used for copying, I'd think it's 'mostly' intended for moving - but perhaps not)?  Also - `list` itself does have a move constructor, but I suppose that doesn't necessarily imply that `T` needs to have a move constructor.  But it would seem a bit conceptually odd to be able to move a list of elements that themselves can't be moved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MSVC uses the copy constructor of `std::list` because its move constructor is throwing. During reallocation, if the move constructor throws, `std::vector` cannot provide strong exception guarantee as required by the standard.

In your case, the vector does not have any element before reallocation, so it appears that the copy constructor is not called, but that doesn't mean the copy constructor is not needed.

`std::list` in libstdc++ and libc++ has `noexcept` move constructor. This is permitted but not required by the standard.

Comment: Thanks for this!  I wonder why `list`s move constructor, but not copy constructor, throws, in VC++.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum The copy constructor might throw, but vector can recover by reverting back to original storage. (For move it's not guaranteed that the moved-from elements are still usable.)

Comment: One detail: You've written `during reallocation, ...`.  I'd think the comments would also apply during allocation of the vector (i.e., construction of the vector) - am I right?

Comment: Actually - I see now that there'd be "nothing to revert back to" in the case of *allocation*.  So, it does seem the comments only apply to reallocation.

Comment: Wow, this question and answer really got me thinking about exception guarantees, `noexcept` and all that.  (And its relationship to `const`.)  Thanks for pointing the way!